# Want to Build 2 Applications in 2 different jdk and then Run in 2 Tomcat servers

Tags: java, tomcat, build, java-6

I have 2 separate applications to build (using maven command) and run in 2 different Tomcat servers.

My 1st appl. should be built in `jdk-6`, while the 2nd appl. in `jdk-7` and then deploy the `.war` file in Tomcat's `webapps` folder.

I am currently changing the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` separately to build these two appl. everytime.
It's a hectic and time consuming process. **Is there any other alternative to build two applications simultaneously in different jdk version at the same time?**

Again, I need to run both applications at the same time in my local servers, one in `Tomcat-6.0.44` and other in `Tomcat-7.0.47`.

I did the below changes in `server.xml` files to configure port numbers in these two Tomcat versions.

in 1st,

```
<Connector port="8080" ...>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

in 2nd,

```
<Connector port="8086" ...>
<Server port="8007" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

But still I cannot run both the local servers at a time.
While one server is up, the other is not being up. **Please suggest me an alternative on this problems.**

Comment: Set up virtual machines or containers?

Comment: If on linux have two copies of tomcat and two init.d scripts

Comment: in Windows platform

Answer (score 0):

use docker, it mach perfectly for the kind of scenario u have